# Making an overlay window with jquery css(3) and HTML(5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom-manipulation

I am looking to create an overlay effect (modal) type effect on my website, I have one working already that is a fixed width and height, but I want it to fill 85% of the available screen space?

How can I achieve this?

My old code looks like this,

```
$('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
            $('#lightbox').css({
                    position:'fixed',
                    left: ($(window).width() - $('#lightbox').outerWidth())/2,
                    top: ($(window).height() - $('#lightbox').outerHeight())/2
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the overlay to fill 85% of the screen space? Then you need to calculate the required width/height & x/y coordinates for that.

```
var targetProcent = 85;
var targetWidth = $(window).width() * (targetProcent / 100);
var targetHeight = $(window).height() * (targetProcent / 100);   
var targetX = ($(window).width() - targetWidth) / 2;
var targetY = ($(window).height() - targetHeight) / 2;

$('#overlay').width(targetWidth);
$('#overlay').height(targetHeight);
$('#overlay').css({
    "position": "absolute", 
    "top": targetY+"px", 
    "left": targetX+"px"
});
```

Alot of the variable assignments could probably be cut out, but left them in for clarity.

Comment: Many thanks for this, is there a way to recalculate the width if the window gets resized?

Comment: Wrap it in a function and call it on $(window).resize() - And please do accept my answer if you find that it solved your problem :)